# How to use find to get only string sequence, not within other words

Tags: search

How do I use the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> find to get only `a` in the text `a apple`, instead of highlighting both `a` and `a` in the word "apple".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for "a " (note the space after the letter), you'll get all words that end in  the letter a. You could also search for " a " which will show all the words "a" surrounded by spaces on both sides.